# Can't find View template in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is my `users_controller.rb` code:

```
  ...
  def edit
    @user = @current_user
  end

  def update
    @user = @current_user # makes our views "cleaner" and more consistent
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      flash[:notice] = "Account settings updated."
      redirect_back_or_default account_url
    else
      render :action => 'edit'
    end
  end
  ...
```

I have the following views/users:

1. new.html.erb
2. password.html.erb
3. profile.html.erb
4. show.html.erb

Everytime I try to update my user account settings, the following pops up:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template users/edit.erb in view path app/views:vendor/plugins/admin_data/app/views):
  app/controllers/users_controller.rb:46:in `update'
```

It's not the fault of `admin_data` is you are curious. It's the controller. What have I done wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, if you want the update action to return to :show, you should change

```
render :action => 'edit'
```

to

```
render :action => 'show'
```

otherwise, it will of course look for edit.html.erb or edit.erb

Second, if you use 'show' for letting the user edit his/her information, why do you actually have the :edit action in your controller? If you don't use it, you should probably remove the following:

```
def edit
  @user = @current_user
end
```

Answer (score 2):

unless you tell the `edit` method to render something else or redirect to some where, the default is that it will look for a template of edit.erb...

Comment: My user updates their details in "show.html.erb". How do I get the controller to save and redirect back to there? Thanks.